# What is the literal meaning of 　”いいかげんにしろ！”?

Tags: words, expressions

Some translations for the expression いいかげんにしろ！ are:

> that's enough!;  cut it out!;  get a life!

If the correct kanji of this expression is 好い加減, what is the literal meaning of both 好い and 加減 in this expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- 好い 'good, preferable'
- 加減 'adjustment (by addition and subtraction)'
- 好い加減にしろ literally 'make/leave it to the right/reasonable/acceptable/tolerable degree'

いい加減 can also be used with a negative connotation with the meaning "sloppy" (almost opposite of the original meaning) as in the sentence given in yadokari's comment to this question. As for why, that may be a good independent question; there are some other words like that.

Comment: thanks. I saw this example on space alc, but perhaps it is a mistake? { いいかげんにしたら駄目よ。
No fooling around ［about］.} I don't see how this example would correlate.